# Mute Cordova plugin cordova-plugin-camera-preview

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, camera, cordova-plugins

I'm developing an app in Cordova, using a plugin for video screen capture, a 'self' style, the plugin natively implemented the processes of the camera in android and ios, but in ios at the moment of image capture, it does the camera noise, on the android I managed to remove, can someone give a light? follow the ios plugin source:

https://github.com/luispimenta/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/tree/master/src/ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve by editing the ios font : 
https://github.com/luispimenta/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/commit/dcc1edf4fc3769729cca4ff449483ed495c2aa92